# Wrong query for table loop?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I just want to ask your help about my table query, everytime when button is click, a new table will display. Instead of only a row will update to a table, an entire table display behind is the old table. Please help me review my code.Thanks

demo.insert.php

```
$dbHost = 'localhost'; // usually localhost
$dbUsername = 'root';
$dbPassword = 'thartpc';
$dbDatabase = 'hospital';
$db = mysql_connect($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword) or die ("Unable to      connect to Database Server.");
mysql_select_db ($dbDatabase, $db) or die ("Could not select database.");

$sql_check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages order by med_id desc");

if(isSet($_POST['content2'])){
    $content2=$_POST['content2'];
    $content3=$_POST['content3'];
    mysql_query("insert into messages(medname, quantity) values    ('$content2','$content3')");
    $sql_in= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages order by med_id desc");
    $r=mysql_fetch_array($sql_in);
}

?>

<?php

require_once 'config.php';
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages order by med_id desc") or die   ("could not search");
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);   

?>
<div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading" class="panel-title">
            <h7>Name</h7>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body" style="padding-top:30px">
<?php
echo "
            <table class='table table-hover';>
                <tr>
                    <td style='border:1px solid; color:gray' align='center'> ID</td>
                    <td style='border:1px solid; color:gray' align='center'>Name</td>
                    <td style='border:1px solid; color:gray' align='center'>Quantity</td>
                </tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    echo "
                <tr>
                    <td style='border:1px solid; color:gray' align='center'>".$row['med_id']."     </td>
                    <td style='border:1px solid; color:gray'  align='center'>".$row['medname']." </td>
                    <td style='border:1px solid; color:gray'  align='center'>".$row['quantity']."</td>
                </tr> ";
}
echo "      </table>";  

?>    
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

inserting.php

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['search'])){
    $globalpid = $_POST['search'];
    $_SESSION['search'] = "$globalpid";
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"       "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

        <link rel="stylesheet"    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">
        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap- theme.min.css">
        <title>Insert Record with jQuery and Ajax</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $("#v").click(function(){
                var element = $(this);
                var test2 = $("#content2").val();
                var test3 = $("#content3").val();
                var dataString = 'content2='+ test2+'&content3='+ test3;
                if(test2==''){
                    alert("Please Enter Some Text");
                }else{
                    $("#flash").show();
                    $("#flash").fadeIn(400).html('<img src="http://tiggin.com/ajax-loader.gif"       align="absmiddle">&nbsp;<span class="loading">Loading Comment...</span>');
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "demo_insert.php",
                        data: dataString,
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(html){
                            $("#display").after(html);
                            document.getElementById('content2').value='';
                            $("#flash").hide();
                        }
                    });
                }
                return false;
            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
        require_once 'pharmacyheader.php';
        require_once 'pharmacysearch.php';
        require_once 'patientquery.php';
    ?>
        <div class="container">
            <form  method="post" name="form" action="">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="panel panel-info">
                        <div class="panel-heading"><h7>Name A - F</h7></div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <select class="form-control" id="content2" name="content2">
                                <option id="0" style="width:100px"></option>
    <?php
        require_once 'config.php';
        $medicine = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM medicine");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($medicine)) {
            echo '<option id="' . $row['medicinename']  . '"';
            echo ' value="' . $row['medicinename'] . '"';
            if($row['brandid'] == $row['medicinename']) {
                echo ' selected="selected"'; 
            }
            echo '>';
            echo $row['medicinename'];
            echo '</option>';               
        }
    ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>                      
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="panel panel-info">
                        <div class="panel-heading"><h7>Quantity</h7></div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <select class="form-control" id="content3" name="content3">
                                <option id="0" style="width:100px"></option>
    <?php
    require_once 'config.php';
    $quantity = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM quantity");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($quantity)) {
        echo '<option id="' . $row['quantityname']  . '"';
        echo ' value="' . $row['quantityname'] . '"';
        if($row['quantityid'] == $row['quantityname']) {
            echo ' selected="selected"'; 
        }
        echo '>';
        echo $row['quantityname'];
        echo '</option>';               
    }
    ?>                                  
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row"><br />
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <input type="submit" value="Add"  id="v" name="submit" class="form-control"      />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div style="height:7px"></div>
        <div id="flash" align="left"  ></div>
        <div id="display" align="left"></div>
        <script     src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script   src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js">       </script>
        <script src="typeahead.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script   src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js">         </script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There must be a Primary Key in your table "message" and write where condition with your Primary Key to display the result.

Comment: yes the med_id is the primary key

Comment: While executing SELECT query after INSERT the value, better you use LAST_INSERT_ID() or something like that which will return last insert primary key ID then use that primary key to fetch the row data and display

Comment: Why do you use .after ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so when looking at your code I can see this :

- You use ajax to retrieve a table with content
- You have a .display element which is supposed to receive the ajax data

SO, each time you call your .ajax, you receive a new complete table in return (check your demo_insert.php). To put the new content in the ".display" item, you use jquery ".after" (you should check how it works btw http://api.jquery.com/after/ )

.after is supposed to ADD something AFTER something else. So, it sounds logical that your ajax return (complete table) is added AFTER ".display" since you ask jquery to do that.

What you should do is just REPLACE your ".display" content with the .ajax response...

```
$('#display').html(html);
```

for example, or something like this...

Comment: can you help me further?

Comment: On the first select option, the value on it will diminish after button click but not on the second select option. How will I do that?

Comment: I can see NO code that has influence on the option values anywhere... need more details about what you are asking...

Comment: i mean the display value on the select option will refresh and return to empty while the second option value I selected still there after button click? any idea.

Comment: Check your eventhandler code, you say that something should happen after click, then you have to make it happen into the click event handler code...

Comment: You are doing this : "document.getElementById('content2').value='';" on success ! So, your content2 is "updated" or at least "changed". BUT you do not change anything about content3... is that what you're asking?

Comment: yes, thanks i just add a new getelement for content3 and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the below code,

```html
echo "<table class='table table-hover';>
<tr>
<td style='border:1px solid; color:gray' align='center'> ID</td>
<td style='border:1px solid; color:gray' align='center'>Name</td>
<td style='border:1px solid; color:gray' align='center'>Quantity</td>

</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 

{
echo "
<tr>
<td style='border:1px solid; color:gray' align='center'>".$row['med_id']."     </td>
<td style='border:1px solid; color:gray'  align='center'>".$row['medname']." </td>
<td style='border:1px solid; color:gray'  align='center'>".$row['quantity']."</td>

</tr> ";

}
echo "</table>";
```

I think this code is executed each and every time ajax call is made.

The butter solution is that put "table" tag where you made ajax call and only append tr content from ajax response.

This may help you out.

Let me know if you have any query

Thanks

Comment: actually, am not that good in ajax, to query for table. how i will i performed ajax query?